# SQL SERVER 2005 Self Joins output

Tags: sql, join

HI 
I am looking for some help I just can't seem to get my head how self joins work. I have this sql code

```
select Persno'Name',convert(char(20), A_Date , 13)'Logins',acode 
from atrail as LOGIN 
where acode = 'LOGIN' OR acode = 'LOGOUT'
order by a_date desc
```

Which produces a list of User names and when the have logged in and out. What I am trying to acheive is to get anther column with the LOGOUT date next to the date they logged in date so that it is easyer to see when they logged in and out.

Thanks

Andy

Comment: you should check the format and spelling.

Comment: also, the requirement isn't clear. Do you want to see a list of each user's login and associated logout? Can you give us the table definition so that we can see what other columns we have to work with?

Comment: What besides the fact it's the next logout associates a particular logout with its login?  Do you have a sessionid or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be another way to achieve it:

```
SELECT Name, [LOGIN] as login_date, [LOGOUT] as logout_date
FROM
(
    SELECT Persno Name,convert(char(20), A_Date , 13) Logins, acode
    FROM atrail 
    WHERE acode = 'LOGIN' OR acode = 'LOGOUT'
    ORDER BY a_date DESC
) AS login_table
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Logins) FOR acode IN ([LOGIN],[LOGOUT])
) AS pvt_table
ORDER BY login_date DESC
```

This is considering that for each login date there is a logout date, and that for each person there is just one login and one logout row.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
select      LOGIN.Persno  AS Name,
            LOGIN.a_date  AS login_date,    --//convert here as you like
            LOGOUT.a_date AS logout_date    --//convert here as you like

from        atrail as LOGIN

left join   atrail as LOGOUT
        ON  LOGOUT.Persno= LOGIN.Persno
        AND LOGOUT.acode = 'LOGOUT'

        AND LOGOUT.A_Date= (SELECT  TOP 1 x.A_Date
                            FROM    atrail x
                            WHERE   x.Persno = LOGIN.Persno
                                AND x.A_Date >= LOGIN.A_Date
                                AND x.acode = 'LOGOUT'
                            ORDER BY x.A_Date)
where       LOGIN.acode = 'LOGIN' 
order by    LOGIN.a_date desc
```

Will produce results in the format:

```
Name        login_date  logout_date
----------- ----------- -----------
pippo       2008-01-01  2008-01-03
```